# Dedekind cuts help

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble understanding dedekind cuts. I know what they are  and could find it if it was in a real line. but i am having difficulty understanding these 2 problems

Let $(A_1, A_2)$ be a Dedekind  cut  of $Q$.   Prove  that  if $x < a$ and  $a \in A_1$  then
$x \in A_1$.

Prove that  if $x > a$ and $a \in A_2$  then  $x \in A_2$

Also

Let $(A_1, A_2)$ and $(B_1, B_2)$ be Dedekind cuts of $Q$. Prove that  either $A_1 \subseteq B_1$  or $A_1 \supseteq B_1$ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $x\notin A_1$.
Then $x\in A_2$ because $A_1\cup A_2=\mathbb Q$.
Then $a<x$ because $a\in A_1$ and $x\in A_2$.
This contradicts $x<a$, hence x\in A_1$.

The second question works the same way.

Assume neither $A_1\subseteq B_1$ nor $A_1\supseteq B_1$.
Then there exists $x\in A_1\setminus B_1$ and $a\in B_1\setminus A_1$.
If $x<a$ then $a\in B_1$ implies $x\in B_1$ by the previous result - contradiction.
If $x>a$, then $x\in A_1$ implies $a\in A_1$ by the previous result - contradiction.
Therefor $x=a$, even more contradiction.

Comment: amazing. I did part a by my self and i got it by contradiction it was actually just question 2 that bothered me. Thanks a lot

Comment: (+1) can you recommend any book in which the basic algebraic operations has been defined and explained using dedkind cuts ?